# initialization vector on Aes

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I save value for initialization vector (in a public variable) when i encrypt plaintext and pass that value for initialization vector when i decrypt ciphertext. I have an error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." how  to fix that ?

```
public static string Decript(byte[] encryptedMessage, byte[] iv,byte[] privateKey) 
        {
            using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.Key = privateKey;
                aes.IV = iv;
                // Decrypt the message 
                using (MemoryStream plaintext = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(plaintext, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {                          
                        cs.Write(encryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.Length);
                        //cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        cs.Close();
                        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext.ToArray());
                        return message;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You'll need to provide us with the encryption routine as well. Padding errors occur because of invalid ciphertext, key or IV (the latter only for shorter messages). Why do you only assume that the IV is to blame?

Comment: Encrypt and Decrypt routine are well, because I have taken from MSDN.
For more explain, i have adapted (MSDN) code, i suppose that the error is because functions for  encryption and decryption are independent from each other. Encryption is become and return ciphertext. Function for decrypt  take argument iv who is generate in encrypt function. and happen error :Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. (sorry for my language ).

Comment: The code itself seems OK to me, there is nothing for us to go on. I can only tell that in about 70% of the cases encoding errors are to blame. Voting to close :(